# Get Excel row number via MS Excel

Tags: python, excel

I have the code below, it use for looking a match cell value and return the row of match cell value, such as looking value is 'LogiGear' at cell D57 (row 58), it will return the row 58.
I wanna improve this code, just looking for D column only.
I don't know why it return the error 'invalid class string'.

Any advice?

```
'''
get excell row number via MS
'''

def GetExcellRowNumberViaMS(strFile, strSheet, text):
    try:
        bFound = False
        #Create an instance of Excel.Application        
        xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
                    lnRowNumber=0;
                    i = 1
                    lastrow = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                    lastcol = xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                    while(i<65000 and bFound ==False):
                        if(i == lastrow+1):
                            break
                        j = 1
                        while(j<256):
                            if(j == lastcol+1):
                                break
                            value = str(xlSheet.Cells(i,j).Text)
                            if(value.strip() == str(text).strip()):
                                lnRowNumber = i
                                bFound = True
                                break
                            j = j + 1
                        i = i + 1     
                    return lnRowNumber
    except Exception:
        return 0
```

Comment: The code you've pasted is quite long. It's not easy to see which part is causing the problem. Could you try editing the code to remove the parts which aren't relevant to your problem? That would make it easier for us to work with. Some instructions for that are here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: As an aside, your problem might be more easily solved using the `xlrd` library for Python.

Comment: I have edited my code. I am using win32com. Please help with win32com

Comment: The edited version of your code won't run. Can you edit it so that it will run when copy-pasted into a `.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

When asking a question, it's helpful to include a small example of the expected input and output. (You should do this for future questions.)

Here's an example I have made up in Excel. We want to find the row that is a `Vegetable`.

[image]

The code you originally posted searches all rows and columns. When simplified and written in a "pythonic" style, it looks like:

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
worksheet = excel.ActiveSheet # The currently open worksheet, in the currently open file.

# This version searches all rows and columns.
for row_num in range(worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count):
    for col_num in range(worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count):
        # Note Python's range() counts from 0 and Excel counts from 1
        value = worksheet.Cells(row_num + 1, col_num + 1).Value
        print ("Value at row %i, column %i is `%s`" % (row_num, col_num, value))
        if value == "Vegetable":
            print "Hooray! Row %i is a vegetable!" % row_num
```

The output looks like:

```
...
Value at row 4, column 0 is `5.0`
Value at row 4, column 1 is `Eggplant`
Value at row 4, column 2 is `Vegetable`
Hooray! Row 4 is a vegetable!
Value at row 5, column 0 is `6.0`
...
```

The above code loops over all column numbers. You can tell it to only look at one column, by fixing `col_num` to be a certain number.

```
for row_num in range(worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count):
    col_num = 2 # Fixed to look at column 2 only
    # Note Python's range() counts from 0 and Excel counts from 1
    value = worksheet.Cells(row_num + 1, col_num + 1).Value
    print ("Value at row %i, column %i is `%s`" % (row_num, col_num, value))
    if value == "Vegetable":
        print "Hooray! Row %i is a vegetable!" % row_num
```

The output now looks like:

```
Value at row 0, column 2 is `Fruit`
Value at row 1, column 2 is `Fruit`
Value at row 2, column 2 is `Fruit`
Value at row 3, column 2 is `Fruit`
Value at row 4, column 2 is `Vegetable`
Hooray! Row 4 is a vegetable!
Value at row 5, column 2 is `Fruit`
```

Notice that only one line of code was changed.

---

Finally,

```
except Exception:
    return 0
```

Catching **all** exceptions is horrible practice. It prevents you from seeing errors. If you can't see an error, you can't debug it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.